# Spring Qualifier, service implementation when application starts

Tags: java, spring

(spring version is 4.1.6)
I have a service Interface "*ContractService*" that retreives contracts of a person.
2 service classes **ContratServiceImpl** & **ContratServiceImplWeb** implementing this interface.
**ContratServiceImpl** calls dao to retreive data
**ContratServiceImplWeb**  calls web service...

The Interface *ContractService* is used by another service (UTService):

```
 @org.springframework.stereotype.Service
    @Transactional(value="transactionManager")
    public class UTServiceImpl implements UTService {

        @Autowired @Qualifier(...<variable.propeties>...)
        private ContractService contractService;
   ...
}
```

Here are services implementing the interface that can be in

```
@Service("ContratServiceImplWeb") @Transactional(value="transactionManager")
class ContratServiceImplWeb implements ContratService {
...
}

@Service("ContratServiceImpl") @Transactional(value="transactionManager")
class ContratServiceImpl implements ContratService {
...
}

Configuration class
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ImportResource(value={ "classpath:sessionFactory-datasource-spring.xml", "classpath:contrat_factories.xml"} )
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xxx.core.service.impl"
                              , "com.xxx.core.dao.impl"}
)
public class ContextCoreServiceConfiguration {

}
```

When my application starts I would like to "qualify" ContractService with ContratServiceImpl  or ContratServiceImplWeb  depending an external configuration file (.properties or XML) where bean names are set.

How can I do this ?

----- Last comments -------
contractServiceImpl & contractServiceImplWeb are set as @service and scanned  by configuration.

In "UTServiceImple" class, 1 of the 2 classes need to be @autowired with a discriminating parameter (may Profile ?). This is not the only group of classes that is concerned.

Profile should not be the same from a couple to another. 
So, I have to set a profile for each group of classes ?

Comment: Do you need to use both implementations at runtime or just one that doesn't change dynamically, depending on a configuration setting?

Comment: Just one, set when application starts. No dynamic change

Comment: Just use Spring profiles, as @José Carlos says in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I guess Spring profiles is exactly what you are looking for.

They let you choose a specific bean implementation dynamically based on a parameter (active profile).

For detailed information, please have a look [here if you are using boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html) or [here if using raw spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles-java).

Answer (score 0):

You are close.  You want your `ContractService` declaration to look more like this:

```
@Autowired
private @Qualifier("contractServiceImpl") ContractService contractServive;
```

This of course presumes that your `ContractServiceImpl` bean was correctly configured and created, either manually or using the `@Service` or `@Component` annotation on your class.

Answer (score 0):

I post the solution. I used @Profiles. It really feeds my needs.
Thanks for having given me this information.

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service
@Transactional(value="transactionManager")
public class UTServiceImpl implements UTService {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UTServiceImpl.class);

    // SERVICES
    @Autowired
    private VerificationHabilitationService verificationHabilitationService;

    @Autowired
    private ContratService contratService;
...
}
```

Interface referenced in the main service

```
public interface ContratService {

    Set rechercheIdentifiantAdherent(String numeroImmatriculation);
...
}
```

Database Service

```
@Service("ContratServiceDb") @Transactional(value="transactionManager") @Profile("contratServiceDb")
class ContratServiceImplDb implements ContratService {

    private Logger logger = null;

    @Autowired
    private ContratFactory contratFactory;
...
}
```

Web Service

```
@Service("ContratServiceWeb") @Transactional(value="transactionManager") @Profile("contratServiceWeb")
class ContratServiceImplWeb implements ContratService {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ContratServiceImplWeb.class);

    @Autowired
    private ContratFactory contratFactory;
...
}
```

Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ImportResource(value={ "classpath:sessionFactory-datasource-spring.xml", "classpath:contrat_factories.xml"} )
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xxx.core.service.impl"
                              , "com.xxx.core.dao.impl"}
)
public class ContextCoreServiceConfiguration {

}
```

For each implementation classe I define a Pofile : contratServiceDb, contratServiceWeb. When context is initialized I set active profile (using external properties file). Then, services matching profiles are autowired. See below :

```
String configCoreClass = servlet.getInitParameter("contextCoreConfigurationClass");
            String[] profiles = { PropertiesHelper.getProperty(PropertiesHelper.PROPERTY_SERVICE_CONTRAT)
                                 ,PropertiesHelper.getProperty(PropertiesHelper.PROPERTY_SERVICE_ADHERENT) 
            };
            AnnotationContextCoreLocator.getInstance().getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles(profiles);
            AnnotationContextCoreLocator.getInstance().register( Class.forName(configCoreClass) );
            AnnotationContextCoreLocator.getInstance().refresh();
```